# php get namespace of included file

Tags: php, namespaces

```
//file foo.php
<?php
namespace foo;
class foo{
    function __construct(){
        echo "hello";
    }
}
?>

//file index.php
<?php
require_once("foo.php");
echo __NAMESPACE__;
?>
```

My question is, from my index.php file, is it possible to know what the namespace of foo.php is without reading the file contents and doing a regular expression on it?  That just seems like a lot of overhead.

///EDIT

I'd really like to be able to dynamically add the namespace to the included file.

```
<?php
namespace dynamic;
require_once("foo.php");
echo __NAMESPACE__;
?>
```

I want to allow for third-party plugins, but php namespaces seems terrible.  I don't want to have the plugin editors have to create a namespace.

Comment: Is it possible to just use the keyword "use" IE: "use foo". Sorry -- not sure if this will work or not though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. But you could trick it this way round:

```
//file foo.php
<?php
  namespace foo;
  //...
  return __NAMESPACE__;  // must be last line
?>
```

And for reading it out:

```
//file index.php
<?php
  $ns = require_once("foo.php");
```

Comment: n.b. returning values from includes may be regarded as bad practice, as it is not traditional behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could scan the class namespace. It contains namespaces. It's the PHPUnit way of doing things. So i.e.:

```
$namespaces = get_current_namespaces();

include 'plugin/main.php';

$newNamespaces = get_current_namespaces(); 
array_diff($namespaces, $newNamespaces)
```

Here is how you can implement `get_current_namespaces()`: [is it possible to get list of defined namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225971/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-defined-namespaces)

Comment: I am not arguing, but this way, you will catch only "new" namespaces.

Comment: You're right @Nick. What it should be, is a variant of the function http://stackoverflow.com/a/5227353/181664 to detect all newly defined classes and get the namespace off that instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the file, you can simply extract the namespace form it :).

```
function extract_namespace($file) {
    $ns = NULL;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if (strpos($line, 'namespace') === 0) {
                $parts = explode(' ', $line);
                $ns = rtrim(trim($parts[1]), ';');
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $ns;
}
```

And you will be not constrain to return something at the end of file that can be broke from exit or other return instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the fairly laborious manual way to do this.

Like discussed at top the process itself is simple:

1. get your list of files for each file. Now for each file:
2. create a random namespace id
3. trim file and replace the first start tag
4. add namespace id and start tag to file
5. write to  temp file
6. import temp file
7. do any reflection required then cleanup

I've got an example with some zend here.... probably not the most efficient but it works.

```
<?php
//first setup zend
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__)."/../zend/library/");
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace(dirname(__FILE__)."/../zend/library/");

//include my extender class
class Zend_Reflection_File_WithNamespace extends Zend_Reflection_File {
    public function getFunctionsWithNamespace($namespace = '', $reflectionClass = 'Zend_Reflection_Function')
    {
        $functions = array();
        foreach ($this->_functions as $function) {
            $newName = $namespace . "\\" . $function;
            $instance = new $reflectionClass($newName);
            if (!$instance instanceof Zend_Reflection_Function) {
                require_once 'Zend/Reflection/Exception.php';
                throw new Zend_Reflection_Exception('Invalid reflection class provided; must extend Zend_Reflection_Function');
            }
            $functions[] = $instance;
        }
        return $functions;
    }
}

//find file(s)
$startDir = 'hello/';
//$tempDir = 'php://temp/resource=';
$tempDir = 'temp/';
$fileList = scandir($startDir);

function ppPrintR($data) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}

//Now loop through each file, first writing to temp, including and then testing
foreach ($fileList as $key => &$fileItem) {
    if (is_file($startDir . $fileItem)) {
        //Take file and convert it
        $findDir = $startDir . $fileItem;
        echo $startDir . $fileItem;

        $inContents = file_get_contents($findDir); 
        $randIden = 'm' . preg_replace('/\.|\s/', '', microtime());

        //Replace the <?[php] at the start of the file with <? namespace xyz;
        $inContents = trim($inContents);
        $addString = 'namespace ' . $randIden . '; ';

        $longTagPos = strpos($inContents,'<?php');
        $shortTagPos = strpos($inContents,'<?');

        if ($longTagPos !== false && $longTagPos < 10) {
            $inContents = str_replace('<?php', '', $inContents);
            $addString = '<?php ' . $addString;
        }
        else if ($shortTagPage !== false && $longTagPos < 10) {
            $inContents = str_replace('<?', '', $inContents);
            $addString = '<? ' . $addString;
        }
        $outContents = $addString . $inContents;

        //Now write and require new temp file
        $tempItem = $tempDir . $fileItem;
        file_put_contents($tempItem, $outContents);
        require($tempItem);

        //Now do normal things
        $reflectedFile = new Zend_Reflection_File_WithNamespace($tempItem);
        echo 'Before<br/>';
        $functions = $reflectedFile->getFunctionsWithNamespace($randIden);
        echo 'After<br/>';

        //Now foreach function, read params and consider execution
        foreach($functions as &$functionItem) {
            echo $functionItem->name . "<br/>";
            $functionParams = $functionItem->getParameters();
            ppPrintR($functionParams);
        }

        //FIXME should clean here
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Though your answer does provide something that works, it is overkill to turn to Zend just to do this. With just PHP itself, there are multiple ways of handling this far quicker. Please consider you're own knowledge and capabilities before turning to a framework ;)

Comment: True, I was just using zend throughout the project, so it wasnt really anything extra. Love to see a non framework solution.