# PHP5: get imported namespaces list

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

Is it possible to get a list of all imported classes/namespaces in a PHP file, in the current context?

For example:

```
namespace A;
use B, C\D;
```

I'd like to get this array:

```
array('B', 'C\D');
```

The reason is that I'm building a Mapper Registry, and I'd like to be able to query this mapper using the aliased class name in the current context, and no the full name.

For example:

```
$registry->getMapper('D');
```

Instead of:

```
$registry->getMapper('C\D');
```

And if possible, I'd like not to hardcode these aliases, if there is a way to get them automatically from PHP!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this class and 'getUseStatements' method.

https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/2.8/lib/Doctrine/Common/Reflection/StaticReflectionParser.php

Or this class and 'getNamespaceAliases' method.

https://github.com/Andrewsville/PHP-Token-Reflection/blob/master/TokenReflection/ReflectionFileNamespace.php

Or perhaps simplified

https://github.com/vaniocz/type-parser/blob/master/src/UseStatementsParser.php

Comment: That looks like a reasonable way to achieve the goal, and from a well-maintained library such as Doctrine Common. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This was discussed recently on the PHP Internals mailing list. The short answer (as I understand it) is no. 
http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=130815747804590&w=2

Comment: Thank you, as said in Ernesta's answer, I'm trying to get the `use` values. I understand that this information is probably useful only for the parser, but I was hoping that this information could be made available to the engine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do so, on your main __construct(), read classes dir, for all available php files for namespaces. ([PHP Manual: glob() - Answer 101017](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#101017)).

Comment: Thank you, actually I'm not looking for a way to get defined namespaces, but rather to get the `use` statements.

Comment: Then write a function for it wich calls user and registers your request.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer for this question:
[is it possible to get list of defined namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225971/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-defined-namespaces)

Has some very handy code which can enumerate all namespaces:

```
    $namespaces=array();
    foreach(get_declared_classes() as $name) {
        if(preg_match_all("@[^\\\]+(?=\\\)@iU", $name, $matches)) {
            $matches = $matches[0];
            $parent =&$namespaces;
            while(count($matches)) {
                $match = array_shift($matches);
                if(!isset($parent[$match]) && count($matches))
                    $parent[$match] = array();
                $parent =&$parent[$match];

            }
        }
    }

    print_r($namespaces);
```

Comment: This returns the list of namespaces for all declared classes, while the question is how to return the *imported* namespaced in the *current* file. Very different!