# How to check the existence of a namespace in php

Tags: php, class, namespaces, exists

I have a **php library** https://github.com/tedivm/Fetch and it uses Fetch namespace and I would like to check its existence in my script.

*My script code:*

```
// Load Fetch
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/vendor/' . strtr($class, '\\', '/') . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;

        return true;
    }
});

if (!class_exists('\\Fetch')) {
  exit('Failed to load the library: Fetch');
}
$mail = new \Fetch\Server($server, $port);
```

but this message is always displayed. But the library is fully working.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to use the entire namespace in the `class_exists` I believe. So something like:

```
class_exists('Fetch\\Server')
```

Comment: sorry, no preceding backslash, updating the answer

Comment: Double slashes are not needed in single quote string. class_exists('Fetch\Server')

Comment: The answer is either strange or incomplete. Please add a note that you need to check the existance of a class in that namespace. So we can't check the namespace alone.

Answer (score 6):

As **George Steel** wrote, it is impossible to check for a namespace. This is because a namespace is not something that exists; only symbols exist *within* namespaces. See below example:

```php
namespace Foo;

class Bar {
}

var_dump(class_exists('Foo')); // bool(false)
var_dump(class_exists('Foo\Bar')); // bool(true)
```

One way to think about it is the way you think about surnames: there's no such thing as a surname, you can't get a list of all surnames "standalone" without checking all people, and you therefore can't determine directly whether a surname exists; but it is part of a full name (FQN) of a person, and so you can retrieve a person's surname, or check if they belong to a surname.

It's just a way to group things. You can look around and compile a list of all things that are "red". But you can't get a list of all colours that exist.

Answer (score 4):

You can't check directly for the existence of a particular namespace, i.e. you'd have to `class_exists('Fetch\\SomeClass')`. See this question too: [is it possible to get list of defined namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225971/is-it-possible-to-get-list-of-defined-namespaces)

Comment: It's a nice ability to do this but can be very (processor) time consuming if you have many classes, which is where you would be most likely to use namespaces.