# What is the most efficient way of getting the namespace of a class in PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, metaprogramming

PHP 5.5 introduced a neat [class name resolution method using the `::class` syntax](https://www.php.net/migration55.new-features#migration55.new-features.class-name). I imagine this made life easier for a lot of people. It certainly did for me.

But now I find myself having to go one step further: getting the namespace of a certain class. This isn't a hard programming task. It can be achieved with string operations or arrays:

```
$parts = explode('\\', \Foo\Bar\Baz::class);
array_pop($parts);
return implode('\\', $parts); // returns "Foo\Bar"
```

But this is an overkill, since I'm using this a lot (as a means to metaprogramming). It actually shows up as a bottleneck when I profile the application. Anyone got an idea for a more efficient solution?

Comment: To answer a deleted comment: the `__NAMESPACE__` constant would help, if you could figure out a way of using it in a different namespace without having to return the `__NAMESPACE__` from each file. PSR0 does not apply here, since I'm doing metaprogramming. There is no "one file = one namespace" rule. Even if I did stick to PSR0, the project files are managed by external autoloader (Composer). So I have little influence on the autoloading process.

Answer (score 0):

At least

```
$class = \Foo\Bar\Baz::class;
$namespace = substr($class, 0, strrpos($class, '\\'));
```

should be more efficient.

Comment: Where this `get_current_namespaces()` function define?

Comment: Sorry. I just used this function recently in one of my applications, but I did not remember it was a custom function I have written based on [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5227353/3464036).

Comment: Yes, this is faster but it does not reduce the time complexity. I did mention in my question, that strings along with the array solutions are not fast enough. The complexity here is still `O(n)` at best. I'm looking for something more of a `O(1)` (as the `::class` syntax provides).